# Best way to create a tuple out of a list where two numbers in the list equal a sum

Tags: c#

I have visited [this](http://www.testdome.com/Questions/Csharp/TwoSum/908) website to test my knowledge and cannot pass the fourth test. Just wondering what the best way to do it would be. Here is what I have tried and still cannot pass the fourth test.

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
    {
        Tuple<int, int> tuple = null;
        Random randomNumber = new Random(0);
        List<Tuple<int, int>> newList;

        IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> combinations = from itemOne in list
                           from itemTwo in list
                           where itemOne + itemTwo == sum
                           select tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(list.IndexOf(itemOne), list.IndexOf(itemTwo));

        newList = combinations.ToList();

        if (newList.Count > 0)
        {
            return newList[randomNumber.Next(0, newList.Count)];
        }
        else
        {
            return tuple;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried:

```
   public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
    {
        Tuple<int, int> tuple = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            int numberToCompare = list[i];
            int currentNumber = i;

            while (currentNumber != list.Count)
            {
                if (list[currentNumber] + numberToCompare == sum)
                {
                    tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(i, currentNumber);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentNumber++;
                }
            }

            if (tuple != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return tuple;
    }
```

Both pass the first 3 tests but not the fourth.

Comment: What specific problems do you have with your code?

Comment: Apparently the performance of my code is not efficient based off of the results in the test.

Comment: I am just looking for a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could think about using a dictionary, in which it only takes O(1) to check if key exists. 
If that list would get large like 2M items that would save a lot of processing. Didn't do any checks for dictionary size as those numbers can be negative I guess.

So I save each value with its last index found in that list (since it doesn't matter which index you return). Then for each value you check you can deduce the other number you are searching for (`sum - value`). That leaves only checking the dict for it and voila :)

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    Dictionary<int,int> indexOfValue= new Dictionary<int, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        indexOfValue[list[i]] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        int value = list[i];
        int needed = sum - value;
        if (indexOfValue.ContainsKey(needed))
        {
           return new Tuple<int, int>(i, indexOfValue[needed]);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running on a single loop.

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)  {
        int needed;
        Dictionary<int, int> indexOfValue = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++){
            needed = sum - list[i];
            if (indexOfValue.ContainsKey(needed)) {
                return new Tuple<int, int>(i, indexOfValue[needed]);
            }

            indexOfValue[list[i]] = i;
        }

        return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a cartesian product or full join with the list, itself and their respective index, and just select the pair that matches the criteria, in your case, equals to `sum` :

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    return list
        .SelectMany((x,xi) => list.Select((y, yi) => new
        {
            Left = x, LeftIndex = xi,
            Right = y, RightIndex = yi
        }))
        .Where(x => x.Left + x.Right == sum)
        .Select(x => new Tuple<int, int>(x.LeftIndex, x.RightIndex))
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Or, to fetch a random pair :

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random();
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    return list
        .SelectMany((x,xi) => list.Select((y, yi) => new
        {
            Left = x, LeftIndex = xi,
            Right = y, RightIndex = yi
        }))
        .Where(x => x.Left + x.Right == sum)
        .Select(x => new Tuple<int, int>(x.LeftIndex, x.RightIndex))
        .OrderBy (x => random.Next())
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: No, OP's code evaluate all cross products before returning anything, while mine returns upon finding the 1st match.

Comment: His second solution short circuits, and so is functionally the same.

Comment: Actually, we are both wrong. It is not the same. I returned the  pair of value, while he returned the pair of index.

Comment: The goal is to find the index of the values which when added together equals the sum.

Comment: My second function returns only the first match as well

Comment: I've modified the function to return index instead of value.

Comment: I've added another solution with some randomness.

Comment: I took the original answer provided and made it return the index, however it did not pass the test and neither did the next two solutions.